# Unable to build Library for AWS C++ SDK for Android Platform

Tags: android, xcode, cmake, aws-sdk-cpp

I am doing a sample application to download a file from Amazon S3 using aws-sdk-cpp. I am able to build Libraries and run for iOS and Mac without any hassle. But with target architecture set to ANDROID, i am facing lot of cmake errors.

```
 cmake /Users/darshan/Desktop/AWS-Git/aws-sdk-cpp -DTARGET_ARCH=ANDROID
```

I am trying to build library for this sdk for Android on Mac OS Sierra. Terminal output is shown in below link.

Terminal Output

[image]

I have the environment variables properly set. Here is the value of $PATH

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/darshan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/darshan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:/Users/darshan/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin
```

Can someone please try building this [AWS C++ SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git) on MAC system for ANDROID and check the issue.
Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What versions of Android SDK and Android NDK do you have installed and do you have the appropriate environment variables set correctly?

Comment: ANDROID_SDK 26.0, ANDROID_NDK 15.1. I do have the environment variables set. Please check the edited question above @MorrisonChang

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd aws-sdk-cpp

export ANDROID_NDK="/opt/android-ndk-r12b" // change to your own NDK path

python scripts/build_3rdparty.py --configs="ReleaseDynamic" --parallel=8 --installdir="../Install" --generateClients="0" --architecture=AndroidArm
```